# Calculo de idade usando Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Eu tenho um campo que é para "data de nascimento" *TextFormField* e tenho uma mascara para facilitar a digitação do usuário *(dd/mm/aaaa)* mas preciso de uma validação que, dependendo do que o usuário digitar não ser possível realizar o cadastro ele sendo menor de 18 e maior de 70 anos de idade e no caso essa verificação ficaria para quando o usuário clicar no botão *cadastrar* por exemplo.

```
    FractionallySizedBox(
                            widthFactor: 0.9,
                            child: Container(
                                width: MediaQuery
                                    .of(context)
                                    .size
                                    .width / 1,
                                height: 50,
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  controller: dateController,
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                
                                  
                                  inputFormatters: [
                                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                                    DataInputFormatter(),
                                  ],
                                  validator: (value) {
                                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                      return '';
                                    }
                                      
                                    return null;
                                  },
                                  
                                 
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      errorStyle: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 0.0,
                                      ),
                                      prefixIcon: Icon(
                                      Icons.calendar_today_outlined,
                                        color: darkGreenColor,
                                      ),
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                      ),
                                      labelText: 'Data de Nascimento*',
                                      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black26)),
                                )
                                ),
                          ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiramente obtenha o valor que o usuário digitou utilizando seu controller:

```
String textoDataNascimento = dateController.text; //Exemplo:'30/04/1950'
```

Lembre-se de verificar se esta string é válida (se por exemplo tem o número de caracteres necessários).

Você não forneceu em sua pergunta, mas como você está usando um `DataInputFormatter()` imagino que este texto venha no formato `DD/MM/AAAA`. Se for esse o caso, precisamos obter as informações separadamente:

```
List<String> campos = textoDataNascimento.split('/');
int dia = int.parse(campos[0]);
int mes = int.parse(campos[1]);
int ano = int.parse(campos[2]);
DateTime nascimento = DateTime(ano,mes,dia);
DateTime hoje = DateTime.now();
```

E com isso criamos dois objetos [DateTime](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/DateTime-class.html). É uma classe que representa um instante no tempo, e possui métodos e atributos úteis.

Um deles é o método [difference()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/DateTime/difference.html), que retorna a diferença entre dois objetos DateTime. [Muitas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62170347/10746978) respostas pelo StackOverflow em inglês recomendam esta abordagem. Isto é, você calcula a diferença entre esses dois objetos, verifica o número de dias, e divide por 365:

```
print(hoje.difference(nascimento).inDays~/365); //Não faça isso
```

Porém, como a documentação desse método diz, essa diferença é apenas o número de segundos entre uma data e outra, e consequentemente irá errar em anos bissextos, por exemplo. No presente momento desta resposta, testei essa abordagem com alguém nascido em 28/04/1950 e foram retornados 71 anos quando a diferença é de apenas 70.

Existem outras bibliotecas externas citadas nas respostas acima que também fornecem essa funcionalidade, porém, para calcular apenas uma idade, acredito que a maneira mais fácil seja calcular manualmente, obtendo e comparando com a data de hoje:

```
int idade = hoje.year - nascimento.year;
if (hoje.month<nascimento.month)
  idade--;
else if (hoje.month==nascimento.month){
  if (hoje.day<nascimento.day)
    idade--;
}
print(idade);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

bool overAgeWorker(String birthDateWorker) {
  String datePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";

  DateTime birthDate = DateFormat(datePattern).parse(birthDateWorker);
  DateTime today = DateTime.now();

  int yearDiff = today.year - birthDate.year;
  print(yearDiff);
  int monthDiff = today.month - birthDate.month;
  print(monthDiff);
  int dayDiff = today.day - birthDate.day;
  print(dayDiff);

  return yearDiff > 18 || yearDiff == 18 && monthDiff >= 0 && dayDiff >= 0;
}

void main() {
  print(overAgeWorker("23/02/2004"));
}
```

Fiz essa função que retorna um bool, porém, o dia sempre retorna número negativo quando a data de nascimento é em fevereiro, eu preciso corrigir esse bug, porém não consegui uma lógica pra isso